# How to find the content that are directly copied from other websites?

Tags: duplicate-content

We're managing a client's website for SEO. We have recently found that some of the content on my client's website are directly copied from other websites.

As a solution provider we have recommended to replace the content with original content. Is there are way we can find out this.

Any suggestion to speed up this process would helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/) is a website which can help identify duplicate content.  It won't tell you if you are the original source/authority in Google for the content, but it will find other websites with the same content.  The free version allows xx amount of searches a day and there is a paid version.

However, copyscape doesn't always find duplicated content, so the best, yest slowest, way is searching for snippets of your content within inverted commas in Google.Like so: 
[Click For Google Result](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=100&safe=off&hl=en&pws=0&q=%22All%20the%20world%27s%20a%20stage,%20and%20all%20the%20men%20and%20women%20merely%20players%3a%20they%20have%20their%20exits%20and%20their%20entrances;%20and%20one%20man%20in%20his%20time%20plays%20many%20parts,%20his%20acts%20being%20seven%20ages.%22&oq=%22All%20the%20world%27s%20a%20stage,%20and%20all%20the%20men%20and%20women%20merely%20players%3a%20they%20have%20their%20exits%20and%20their%20entrances;%20and%20one%20man%20in%20his%20time%20plays%20many%20parts,%20his%20acts%20being%20seven%20ages.%22&gs_l=serp.3...20424.21505.0.22006.3.3.0.0.0.0.64.64.1.1.0....0...1c.1.26.serp..3.0.0.zhdWsbPOyMg)

Comment: Use premium version of Copyscape.com. It will be right every time.

Comment: I have used the premium version many times and it hasn't picked up all sites/content that a Google search did.